# Assigning Template Reference Variables with StrictTemplate on?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, typescript

I have a template reference variable that I want to assign to a variable inside a model but I'm not quite sure how to achieve this with strictTemplate on.
The original code without strictTemplate on is:

```
<a #newLink> </a>

<new-panel>
  [parentElement] = "newLink"
>
</new-panel>
```

and the variable inside the model is:

```
@Input() parentElement: ElementRef;
```

This works with strictTemplate off, but with it turned on, it returns a Type 'HTMLAnchorElement' is not assignable to type 'ElementRef' error.
What types should be used for template reference variables when restricted to strict templates?